# FileDialog Crashes Application

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to figure out what could be causing a crash when using FileDialog in my application.

I've tried a pdb trace to see what's going on, but it stops at "if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:" and then just freezes.

```
class databaseOpenWindow(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Choose Database", size=(300,300))
    self.SetBackgroundColour((0,0,0))

    try:
        ico = wx.Icon('icon.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(ico)
    except:
        pass

    self.dir = os.getcwd()
    col = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    col.AddStretchSpacer()
    open = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="Open Database")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getDBPath, open)
    col.Add(open,0,wx.CENTER,10)
    col.AddStretchSpacer()
    new = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, label="New Database")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.NewDB, new)
    col.Add(new,0,wx.CENTER,10)
    col.AddStretchSpacer()
    self.SetSizer(col)
    self.Layout()
    self.Show()

def getDBPath(self, event):
    wildcard = "Database (*.db)|*.db"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose Database To Open",
        defaultDir= self.dir,
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        paths = dlg.GetPaths()
        global session
        global database
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + paths[0])
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        Base.metadata.bind = engine
        DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = DBSession()
        database = os.path.basename(paths[0])
        dlg.Destroy()
        self.Destroy()
        mainGUI()

    elif dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
        dlg.Destroy()
```

It was working fine the first time the button was clicked and now it just freezes the application. I'm using Python 3.7 on Windows 10

Comment: First check that the code underneath isn't the issue. Replace all that code after `if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:` with `print("Ok")`

Comment: Moved the code underneath to separate function, it works now.